# Saber en numero de la semana de un rango de fechas

Tags: php, date

Quisiera obtener el numero de la semana de un rango de fechas

por ejemplo si tengo:

```
$fechaI = '2017-01-'01';
$fechaF = '2017-01-21';
```

entonces son 3 semanas y lo quiero guardar en un `array` que sea

```
$nSena =[1,2,3];
```

donde `1,2,3` es el numero de la semana,

ejemplo dos:

```
$fechaI = '2017-09-'01';
$fechaF = '2017-09-21';
```

entonces:

```
$nSena =[35,36,37,38];
```

intente hacerlo per o lo que logre fue lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$fechaI = new DateTime('2017-09-01');
$fechaF = new DateTime('2017-09-21');
$interval = $fechaI->diff($fechaF);
echo floor(($interval->format('%a') / 7)) ;
```

y me devuelve el numero de semanas en ese rango que serian 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias intentar algo asi:

```
$fechaI = new DateTime('2017-09-01');
$fechaF = new DateTime('2017-09-21');
$semanainicio = $fechaI->format("W");
$semanafin = $fechaF->format("W");

for ($i = $semanainicio; $i <=  $semanafin; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

format te devuelve el numero de semana en el año. Luego lo único que hago es un for para obtener la lista de las semanas. 
Fíjate que aunque sea una sola semana, este código debería a funcionar (pero no lo probé).

Comment: veo un pequeño fallo, si los últimos días de diciembre se meten en la semana 1, por ejemplo 2018, da un array vacío

Comment: @Toni totalmente de acuerdo. Ni idea como arreglarlo ya que pasarias de la semana 54 a la 0, y op no dijo q hacer con eso.

Answer (score 3):

```
   
$firstWeek=date('W',strtotime('2017-01-12'));
$lastWeek=date('W',strtotime('2017-09-12'));
echo json_encode(array_keys(array_fill(($lastWeek<$firstWeek?$lastWeek:$firstWeek),abs($lastWeek-$firstWeek),'0')));
```

Las fechas pueden estar truncadas y no tener por que ser mayor la segunda que la primera, siempre devuelve las semanas en orden.

Para guardar en un array la ultima linea seria:

```
$arr=array_keys(array_fill(($lastWeek<$firstWeek?$lastWeek:$firstWeek),abs($lastWeek-$firstWeek),'0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Completando la respuesta de @gbianchi, intenta hacerlo así:

```
$fechaI = new DateTime('2017-09-01');
$fechaF = new DateTime('2017-09-21');
$semanainicio = (int) $fechaI->format("W"); // Convertimos a entero
$semanafin = (int) $fechaF->format("W");// Convertimos a entero

$nSena = [];
while ($semanainicio <=  $semanafin) {
    $nSena[] = $semanainicio;
    $semanainicio++;
}
echo json_encode($nSena);
```

El resultado sería:

```
[35,36,37,38]
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/UONE10542)</kbd>